# How to disable or edit the spring-data-rest HATEOAS default profile link

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I currently have an entity in my project named "profile" (Using JPA); however api/profile directs you to the application levels detail.  I don't have an option to rename the object's repository using @RepositoryRestResource at this time. Is there a way in the configuration to disable or rename the application level deatils endpoint in Spring Data REST?

```
"profile" : [ {
  "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/profile{?page,size,sort}",
  "templated" : true
}, {
  "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/profile"
} ],
```

Selecting the profile link directs me to

```
  }, {
"rel" : "profile",
"href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/profile/profile"
```

},

Using spring 4.2.1 RELEASE, spring-data-jpa 1.9 & spring-data-rest-core-2.4.0 RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the root resource links with a `ResourceProcessor<RepositoryLinksResource>`

Like this :

```
@Component
public class RootResourceProcessor implements ResourceProcessor<RepositoryLinksResource> {
    @Autowired
    private final EntityLinks entityLinks;

    @Override
    public RepositoryLinksResource process(final RepositoryLinksResource resource) {
        final Link link = entityLinks.linkToCollectionResource(YourResource.class);
        resource.getLinks(); //the root links
        return resource;
    }
}
```